# How do I find all points of discontinuity of the function $f(x)= |x+2|+|x+3|$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, continuity, absolute-value

Basically it is a modulus $\operatorname{fun}^c$. To begin with we'll redefine the function, i.e. $f(x)=|x+2|+|x-3|$.

Taking
$$ u = |x+2| = \begin{cases}
-(x+2), & \text{if $x<0$,} \\
x+2, & \text{if $x=0$,} \\
x+2, & \text{if $x>0$,}
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$ v = |x-3| = \begin{cases}
-(x-3), & \text{if $x<0$,} \\
x-3, & \text{if $x=0$,} \\
x-3, & \text{if $x>0$.}
\end{cases}
$$
we have $f(x)=u+v$.

LHL for u
= -(0+2)
= -2
RHL for u
= 0+2
= 2
Therefore, RHL not equal to LHL.
It is not cont at x=0

LHL for v
= -(0-3)
= 3
RHL for v
= 0-3
= 3
Therefore, RHL not equal to LHL.
It is not cont at x=0

Therefore, it cont at all R-{0}.
Point of discontinuity is 1.

Where I am gng wrong pls anyone help.
Note: THIS NOT A HOME WORK QUESTION. I have used some abbreviation.
Like, cont-continuous.

Comment: Have you learnt a bit about MathJax or TeX? It helps to represent the math symbols more neatly and makes your ideas more readable to most of us.

Comment: Also the function is continuous everywhere.

Comment: Please use Mathjax to format your question. Very hard to follow. Then the function in the title is not the same as the function in the text. And the points where you change the sign in the absolute value is not at $x=0$, but at $x+2=0$ or $x-3=0$

Comment: @Faaria Shaikh, why did you write this in bold letters?

Comment: @Yuki.F Idk abt them.

Comment: I have taken the liberty of editing the first part of your question to use proper formatting.  Please finish the job.  If you need help with the syntax, please see the [MathJax guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Also, please do not use abbreviations---spell out the words, use complete sentences, etc.  Basically, write as though you were communicating with a respected professor.  If you don't show respect to the members of the community here, I doubt that they will receive your work very kindly.

Comment: @Xander Henderson Thank you for dis. I am a new member. I'll mend my ways.

Comment: @FaariaShaikh, would you like to accept the answer? :-)

Comment: @SarGe Yes sure pls if u can....

Comment: Click the check mark ✅ on the left side of the answer.

Comment: @ SarGe Your answer is just a correction. It is not the ans of my question. I thought you got the ans

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean differentiable? The function $g(x)=|x+2|$ is continuous everywhere because it's just the absolute function shifted 2 to the left, and that is continuous. Also $h(x)=|x+3|$ is continuous because it's just the absolute value function shifted 3 to the left. And $f(x)=|x+2|+|x+3|$ is the sum of continuous functions, so it's also continuous.

Comment: The fun^c has a point of discontinuity ie. 0. Any Modulus fun^c has 0 as discontinuous point.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't redefine the modulus function correctly. It should be $$u=\begin{cases} x+2 &, x\ge -2\\ -(x+2) &, x<-2\end{cases}$$ and $$v=\begin{cases} x-3 &, x\ge 3\\ -(x-3) &, x< 3\end{cases}$$

Comment: Oh yeah I did it the same way. Check out

Comment: No, you didn't. See the cases properly.

Comment: I wrote correctly dear. It got mingled after posting.

Comment: Anyways did u got my question??

Comment: @Faaria Shaikh, no, it's not correct. For $u$, cases that I took are $x\ge -2$ and $x<-2$. But, you took $x>0$, $x<0$ and $x=0$. Same for $v$, it is wrong, too.

Comment: Oh yeah, M sorry. I was a bit sleepy yesterday. Ur correct. Thank you